# Migrating from info.cukes to io.cucumber shows no steps status when running the test

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, pom.xml, cucumber-java

My tests run fine with the following in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

the scenario and steps show fine:

[image: steps execution showing beautifully]

But if I move to newer:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

(or even 2.1.0)
the scenario still succeeds but the steps are not displayed anymore:

[image: steps execution not showing]

Runing on IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.1.4

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am having the same issues.

Comment: Not really, I even updated IntelliJ but no luck. I'm sticking to info.cukes for now.

Comment: Yeah I updated to the experimental version..Does not work there aswell. Should be fixed in the next version.

Comment: This should work by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the Event model changed for Cucumber-jvm v2.x (see [release notes](https://cucumber.io/blog/2017/08/29/announcing-cucumber-jvm-2-0-0)) and the IntelliJ plugin has not yet been updated to reflect this (for instance, see this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180970) and the one it links to).

**Please vote for these issues at youtrack if you'd like to see this fixed in IntelliJ!**

Update: This should work by now.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber plugin supporting cucumber.io initially was released for IntelliJ  2017.3 [Release notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.3+173.4301.1+Release+Notes) on Dec 27, 2017. Latest 2017.1.5 was released on Jun 06, 2017 [Release notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.1.4+Release+Notes) I don't think it has a port for cucumber.io.

I can confirm that it works on 2017.2.6 and 2017.3.4. Sometimes I have same issue even on these versions, restart of IntelliJ solves it.